# Get WooCommerce product categories that contain a specific product brand

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I am in the process of developing a webshop where I want a feature that shows, product categories that contain products of a particular brand.

I sell clothes on my webshop, and then if you for example selects the brand "Levis" in the header menu, then in the sidebar on the shop page you should see all the product categories containing products of the brand "Levis". Hope it makes sense.

I have been looking and looking for a solution, but I have not yet succeeded. Somewhere on the web, it says that there is no solution for it, so I have to develop it from scratch.

If it is necessary to develop it from scratch, how do you approach it most easily? I have developed some themes for Wordpress myself, so I know how Wordpress works. Just can't see exactly how to solve this problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Please post the code that you tried

Comment: I haven't tried to develop any code yet as I don't know how to approach it.

I also do not ask for a complete solution to the problem, but just a clue to how others would have solved it if someone has already found a solution or knows where to read about it.

Comment: @JørgenCasper Please, still waiting for your feed back on the answer below…

Answer (score 3):

This can only be done with a custom SQL query using WordPress [`WPDB`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) Class.

Now as there is multiple product brand plugins available for WooCommerce, depending on the plugin that you are using you will have to adjust the correct taxonomy:

- `product_brand` for WooCommerce Brands plugin *(**here by default** in the function below)*
- `yith_product_brand` for YITH WooCommerce Brands plugin
- `pa_brand` for a custom product attribute *(self made)*

Below you will find a custom function that returns an array of WooCommerce product categories Objects based on a product brand term **slug**:

```
// The defined taxonomy here in the function $taxonomy argument is for WooCommerce Product brand plugin
function get_product_categories_from_a_product_brand( $brand_term_slug, $taxonomy = 'product_brand' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT t1.*
        FROM    {$wpdb->prefix}terms t1
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt1
            ON  t1.term_id = tt1.term_id 
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr1
            ON  tt1.term_taxonomy_id = tr1.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr2
            ON  tr1.object_id = tr2.object_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt2
            ON  tr2.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.term_taxonomy_id         
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t2
            ON  tt2.term_id = t2.term_id
        WHERE tt1.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
        AND tt2.taxonomy = '$taxonomy'
        AND  t2.slug = '$brand_term_slug'
    " );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Usage example code in any php file** - Display All related linked product categories names for a product brand slug:

```
$brand_term_slug = 'levis'; // A term slug is required (not the term id or term name)

$results = get_product_categories_from_a_product_brand( $brand_term_slug );

if( ! empty($results) ) {

    $term_names = []; // Initializing an empty array variable

    // Loop through each product category terms:
    foreach ( $results as $result ) {
        $term_id   = $result->term_id; // Term id
        $term_name = $result->slug; // Term slug
        $term_slug = $result->name; // Term name
        $taxonomy  = 'product_cat'; 

        $term_link = get_term_link( get_term( $result->term_id, $taxonomy ), $taxonomy );

        // Example: Set the linked formatted term name in an array
        $term_names[] = '<a class="'.$result->slug.'" href="'.$term_link.'">'.$result->name.'</a>';
    }   

    // Display the linked formatted terms names
    echo '<div class="brand-categories '.$brand_term_slug.'">'.implode(' ', $term_names).'</div>';
}
```

Comment: its working! nice solution!